# Marklogic semantics: treatment of rdf:about attribute values

Tags: rdf, marklogic

I am trying to import an RDF data source (RDF/XML) into Marklogic 8.02 with mlcp 1.3.3.

During import, I am swamped with warnings like this one:

> 15/06/29 15:03:58 WARN contentpump.RDFReader:
>   57fad317-4744-4f88-a8f7-6c21c662ad08.rdf: {W107} Bad URI:
>   
>   Code: 45/UNREGISTERED_NONIETF_SCHEME_TREE in SCHEME: The scheme name
>   has a "-" in it, but it does not start in "x-" and the prefix is not
>   known as the prefix of an alternative tree for URI schemes.

Looking at the source data (RDF/XML), it is caused by statements like this:

> <rdf:Description
>   rdf:about="rvr-jurisprudentie:http%3A%2F%2Flinkeddata.overheid.nl%2Fterms%2Fjurisprudentie%2Fid%2FECLI%3ANL%3ARVS%3A2013%3A549:http%3A%2F%2Flinkeddata.overheid.nl%2Fterms%2Fbwb%2Fid%2FBWBR0005181%2F2986364%2F2015-01-01%2F2015-01-01">

So it looks like ML thinks that this rdf:about attribute contains a URI and complains that it is not a valid one.

So three questions:

1. why does ML think that this has to be a URI. I haven't encountered this problem with other toolsets.
2. is there a switch with which to ignore warnings (Piping output in terminal doesn't seem to work)
3. does this have any further effects down the road (i.e. performance etc.)?

Comment: @RobV thanks a lot. I tested your suggestion for log4j ERROR and it works like a charm. I'll have to discuss first point with the producer of the RDF/XML data source. Still unsure why it is a warning and not an error (instead of warning) if it's going against spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does ML think that this has to be a URI. I haven't encountered
>   this problem with other toolsets.

Because that is what the [RDF/XML syntax specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/#section-RELAXNG-Schema) says:

```
aboutAttr = 
      attribute rdf:about { 
          URI-reference 
      }
```

The `rdf:about` attribute expects to receive a URI and your data does have something that looks mostly like a URI in that attribute:

```
rvr-jurisprudentie:http%3A%2F%2Flinkeddata.overheid.nl%2Fterms%2Fjurisprudentie%2Fid%2FECLI%3ANL%3ARVS%3A2013%3A549:http%3A%2F%2Flinkeddata.overheid.nl%2Fterms%2Fbwb%2Fid%2FBWBR0005181%2F2986364%2F2015-01-01%2F2015-01-01
```

It is using a custom URI scheme but it doesn't conform exactly to [RFC 3986 Generic URI Syntax](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) and thus MarkLogic issues a warning.  However it it still a valid URI if one that likely can't be interpreted by some/all tooling.

> is there a switch with which to ignore warnings (Piping output in
>   terminal doesn't seem to work)

There does not appear to be one, however in the MarkLogic Content Pump [documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/content-pump#id_75840) they show enabling `DEBUG` level messages:

> Edit the file `MLCP_INSTALL_DIR/conf/log4j.properties`. For example,
>   if mlcp is installed in `/opt/mlcp`, edit
>   `/opt/mlcp/conf/log4j.properties`. In `log4j.properties`, set the
>   properties `log4j.logger.com.marklogic.mapreduce` and
>   `log4j.logger.com.marklogic.contentpump` to `DEBUG`. For example,
>   include the following:
>
> ```
> log4j.logger.com.marklogic.mapreduce=DEBUG
> log4j.logger.com.marklogic.contentpump=DEBUG
> ```

Obviously this does the opposite of what you want but since it is just a log4j configuration you can turn down the logging to `ERROR` in the same way as you can turn it up to `DEBUG` as shown in their example.

> does this have any further effects down the road (i.e. performance
>   etc.)?

You may have problems if you need to pass the data to other RDF or SPARQL tools that interpret the URI specification more strictly

Comment: Specifically, ':' is a reserved character according to section 2 of RFC 3986. Since the error is in your RDF source and not in your MarkLogic application, MarkLogic only issues a warning.